# Can someone explain the strange behaviour with indenting during reformatting?

Tags: indentation, formatting

Recently, [someone noticed](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/436#issuecomment-234905144) a strange behaviour with indenting during formatting with my LaTeX plugin, [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). I've researched it, and I've ended up creating a minimal example. Load the following code as a minimal vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
set indentexpr=MyIndent()

function! MyIndent()
  let l:nprev = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
  if l:nprev == 0 | return 0 | endif

  let l:cur = getline(v:lnum)
  let l:prev = getline(l:nprev)

  let l:indent  = max([Count(l:prev, '(') - Count(l:prev, ')'), 0])
  let l:indent -= max([Count(l:cur, ')') - Count(l:cur, '('),   0])

  return indent(l:nprev) + &sw*l:indent
endfunction

function! Count(line, pattern)
  let sum = 0
  while 1
    if match(a:line, a:pattern, 0, sum + 1) == -1
      return sum
    endif
    let sum += 1
  endwhile
endfunction
```

With the above minimal vimrc file, load the following text into a buffer:

```
Therefore, in that case the observed dynamics cannot be truly
Markovian. We can still approximately capture the observed density dynamics
with eq.~\ref{eq:fpe}; however the local coefficients are then effectively
averages over the co-evolving unobserved distribution. For example, $\vec
v(\vec x,t)=\int p(\vec x^u|\vec x,t)v(\vec x,\vec x^u,t)dx^u$. This has some
important consequences. First, the effective Markovian coefficients $\vec v,
\lambda, D$, will generally depend on time, reflecting the time evolution of
the hidden $p(\vec x^u)$ over the time scale of the experiment. Second, the
effective coefficients may also depend on the initial condition: a cell
population started concentrated around label $\vec x_0$ implies a certain
distribution over $x^u$ when sampled at label $\vec x$ some time later; another
population started around $\vec x_1$ carries a different history when it, too,
visits $\vec x$ later. Therefore, for instance the effective drift $\vec v(\vec
x)$ will be different in the two cases. We conclude that, if unobserved degrees
of freedom have dynamics on the time scale of the experiment eq.~\ref{eq:fpe}
is an approximation whose coefficients become \emph{non-universal} (dependent
on intial conditions) and \emph{time-dependent}.
```

Now do `gg=G`, as expected, the indentation does not change. However, if we instead do `gggwG`, it ends up indenting and reformatting the last 4 lines. I've found that while formatting with `gw`, the `getline()` function does not return the expected lines.

My question is: Does anyone understand this behaviour? I suspect it might be an error or bug in Vim, and will submit it as a bug report, unless someone here has an explanation.

Comment: First, `gw` and `=` use different methods of formatting as far as I can tell. `=` uses the `C-indenting` function and `gw` uses the same that `gq` uses (help mentions something about the `textwidth` option). Second, the odd formatting has to do with the open parenthesis. It seems that `gq` is assuming that since you have a non closed parenthesis you want indentation. Try putting open parins elsewhere and you'll see that it is this that causes the indent. I would assume that these should act the same in this instance, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, `=` is not a formatting operator, it is an indent operator. `gw` uses an internal formatter, while `gq` uses the `formatexpr` or `formatprg` (defaults to same as `gw` if nothing else is defined). However, `gw` will also ensure that the formatted lines are indented correctly, and thus will use the indentexpression if it is defined.

Comment: looks like a bug

Comment: OK, I've posted [an issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/951) on the Vim github page. I will close/delete this question if the bug is confirmed.